# When does the CLI cmd return

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm working on some CI tooling and would like to know when the CLI returns.  I know that when I use the portal, the tasks are queued.  I would like to know if the CLI returns when azure receives the request, or when the task is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the cli commands are executed in sync mode(means it returns when the task is finished).

You can go to [the cli command page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest), and see if it's sync or async. For example, the cli `az storage blob copy start` is async(means it returns when azure receives the request). The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the verbiage in the docs.  I am working with web apps and didn't see the (a)sync keywords and so I wasn't sure the default action.